# Making a general purpose data organization contract: how would one create a table in solidity

Tags: database-design, ethereum, solidity

I have read Rob's CRUD Dapp post and I'm now wondering if someone  might know how to create solidity contracts that represent general tables, not application specific, but a contract that could store and retrieve data in an organized way for any application?

That way a developer would have to worry less about organizing their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood your question correctly. 
If I would have to create a contract to store all kinds of data in the form of a table I would use a mapping.

If you have a table like this:

```
| ID   | Product | Price | .... |
---------------------------------
| 123  | Phone   | 1000  | .... |
| 124  | Laptop  | 2000  | .... |
```

You could create a **multi-purpose mapping** for all kinds of tables, where the key represents the ID and the bytes all the data:

```
public mapping(uint256 => bytes);
```

It is very common to pass a bunch of data of which you do not know what form it has as a byte array (you can look at the ERC827 token proposal).

Because the mappings are public getters are automatically created, however keep in mind that **you can only ever get one element at a time** (this is a restriction for mappings and arrays), which makes bulk actions practically infeasible.

You can also not create a custom function to do bulk actions for the user because it is **not possible for functions to return mappings or dynamic arrays**. In addition there is no easy way to get an array of all values of a mapping. You could however either retrieve a fixed amount of elements manually and save them in a fixed length array and return this (very expensive) or you could transform the elements retrieved into a byte array and return them this way.

Also to retrieve an element you must know the product ID, if your users do not know the IDs you could provide them in an public array.

All in all, you should try to store as little data as possible on the blockchain. **Saving data is very expensive** (storing a new value in the storage of contract costs 20000 gas) which is why you practically do not see any contracts that fulfill the purpose you describe.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Imagine you have a website, and you use PHPMyAdmin to manage your SQL database. For some reason, you decide that you would like to store some of your data on Ethereum. Perhaps you know how to develop basic scripts in PHP, but you are not going to write out a complex plan on how you are going to shift some of your existing data onto Ethereum. It would be very useful to just use a smart-contract that's capable of storing your data, and organizing it in a way that could be easily queried in SQL.

Comment: I understand what your plan/goal is, it is my understanding that one way how to store the data is as I described above. The organization and transformation from `bytes` back to the original data format is something that can be moved off-chain. Generally if it is possible to move something off-chain you should because of security and gas cost. Instead of providing this functionality in a smart contract you would offer e.g. a web-based solution which communicates with a minimal smart contract and provides SQL-like querying services.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library to achieve that. https://github.com/petrosDemetrakopoulos/ethairballoons . It is available in npm and you can install it with "npm install ethairballoons".

It offers a level of abstraction over solidity contracts and the only thing you have to do is to define your models in JSON and the deploy them. It will do the job without writing a single line of Solidity.